# What does "Associate To Website" mean?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, create

In Magento 1.9 Customers > Add New > Account Information  What does "Associate To Website" field mean? What's the difference between "Admin" and "Main Website"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field "Associate to Website" is used to associate the customer created with a particular website or to the admin.

1) When user is created with Associate to website as "Admin" then the user will not be able to login in the frontend. For this the values of store_id and website_id stored in database are 0.

2) When user is created with Associate to website as "Some Store(Eg: Main Website)" then the user will be able to login for that particular website. For this the value of store_id and website_it stored in database are the store id and website id respectively of the website with which you have associated the customer with.

Comment: In my case, I have chosen the "Main Website". But the login is worked for me.

Comment: @radhu Sorry for the mistake. By mistake i wrote the word "not" for the second case. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yea, Cool. Thanks @flyingfinner